# Dynamically create a table with row values as columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I need to create a table dynamically based on different values comes from distinct values of type column from tbl1. Please let me know if it is possible using cursor and function below.

Creating `tbl1` with a columns `id`, `type` and `value`.
Creating `tbl2` with a columns `id` ,`gender`.
Function retrieving values into final table using cursors. (creating temp table `dual` for checking what values are being passing.)

```
create table tbl1 (
    id int not null,
    type varchar not null,
    value varchar
);

create table tbl2 (
    id int not null,
    gender varchar not null
);

commit;

insert into tbl1 values (1,'name','A'),(2,'name','B'),(1,'age','10'),(3,'name','C');
insert into tbl2 values (1,'M'),(2,'F');

commit;

--the below crosstab didn't work
SELECT id
     , COALESCE(name, max(name) OVER w)
     , COALESCE(age, max(age) OVER w)
FROM   crosstab(
   'SELECT id::text || row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id, type ORDER BY value) * -1 AS ext_id
         , id, type, value
    FROM   tbl1
    ORDER  BY ext_id, type, value'
   ,$$VALUES ('name'::text), ('age') $$
   ) AS ct (xid text, id int, name text, age int)
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id);

-- FUNCTION: SELECT public.Finaltblfunc1()

-- DROP FUNCTION public.Finaltblfunc1();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.Finaltblfunc1()
    RETURNS setof refcursor 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE
AS $BODY$
DECLARE

/* Declare variables. */
    P_id NUMERIC(10,0);
    P_name VARCHAR(20);
    P_age VARCHAR(3);
    P_gender VARCHAR(1);
    v_leng INTEGER;
    v_leng1 INTEGER;
    v_j bigint;
  v_k VARCHAR(10);

/* Declare cursors. */
    sourcerefcur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT t1.id,
                     (CASE WHEN t1.type = 'name' THEN t1.value ELSE '' END) AS name,
                     (CASE WHEN t1.type = 'age' THEN t1.value ELSE '' END) AS age,
                     t2.gender
                     FROM tbl1 t1 full outer join tbl2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id;
    temprefcur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT distinct t1.type FROM tbl1 t1;
    --targetrefcur2 REFCURSOR;

/* Declare SQL string variables. */
  SQL_STR1 VARCHAR(200):= 'SELECT count(distinct table_name) 
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = ''public'' and table_name = ''finaltable''';

/* Declare error handling variables. */
    err_num TEXT;
    err_msg TEXT;

BEGIN
    /* tables exists or not */
    EXECUTE SQL_STR1 INTO v_j;
    RAISE INFO 'Finaltable check:%',v_j;

    IF (v_j = 0) THEN
            --Creating a Final Table
         create table finaltable (
         id NUMERIC(10,0),
         name varchar(50),
         age varchar(3),
         gender varchar(1)
         );
    ELSE
     --do nothing
    END IF;

    v_leng := 0;
    --open the cursor temprefcur1
    OPEN temprefcur1;

    loop
        --fetch next from temprefcur1 into respective parameters;
        fetch next from temprefcur1 into v_k;

        -- exit when no more row to fetch
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

        v_leng = v_leng +1;     
        raise notice 'v_k:%',v_k;
        raise notice 'v_leng:%',v_leng;     

    end loop;

    return next temprefcur1;

     -- Close the cursor
     CLOSE temprefcur1;

    v_leng1 := 0;
    --open the cursor sourcerefcur1
    OPEN sourcerefcur1;

    loop
         --fetch next from sourcerefcur1 into respective parameters;
         fetch next from sourcerefcur1 into P_id,P_name,P_age,P_gender;

         -- exit when no more row to fetch
         EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

         v_leng1 = v_leng1 +1;
         RAISE INFO 'P_id: %',P_id; --, E'\n';
         RAISE INFO 'P_name: %',P_name; --, E'\n';
         RAISE INFO 'P_age: %',P_age; --, E'\n';         
         RAISE INFO 'P_gender: %',P_gender; --, E'\n';       
         RAISE INFO 'length: %',v_leng1; --, E'\n';

         raise notice 'step insert';
         insert into finaltable values (P_id,P_name,P_age,P_gender);
         insert into dual values (P_id),(P_name),(P_age),(P_gender);
         insert into dual values (v_leng1);
         raise notice 'after step insert';

    end loop;

    return next sourcerefcur1;

    --close sourcerefcur1
    close sourcerefcur1;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    err_num := SQLSTATE;
    err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM,1,100);
    RAISE INFO 'Error: % %', err_num, err_msg;
END;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.Finaltblfunc1()
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have been (hugely) over-complicating things. This should basically do it **all**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS finaltable (
  id     bigint
, name   text
, age    int
, gender text
);


INSERT INTO finaltable(id, name, age, gender)
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
 $$SELECT id, type    , value  FROM tbl1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT id, 'gender', gender FROM tbl2
   ORDER  BY id$$
,$$VALUES ('name'), ('age'), ('gender')$$
   ) AS ct (id int, name text, age int, gender text);
```

Result:

```
id | name |  age | gender
-: | :--- | ---: | :-----
 1 | A    |   10 | M     
 2 | B    | null | F     
 3 | C    | null | null
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=efc4bb88718e912949d87c4bde433699)*

Not sure what the added `COALESCE` was supposed to achieve. I stripped it.

Basics:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Aside: `age` as table column is subject to bitrot. Store birthdays instead (or similar).

Comment: You're creating table manually with static column names. it has to be dynamic and also it should come from tbl1.type column values.

Comment: @RupasaSushma: Sorry, then I failed to understand your question properly. It's a little light on the objective.

Comment: I need to create a table dynamically using temprefcur1 cursor for each distinct row values. Is it possible ?